# Can I undo file operations?

Tags: nautilus, filesystem

When do you think to add the "undo file operations" like Windows does? 
If (for a mistake) I move a file I want to CRTL+Z to undo the operation.

Answer (score 4):

Not with nautilus, the default file manager in gnome. This feature has been discussed

http://live.gnome.org/Nautilus/Undo

And there is a patch http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8689961

But I am not sure if the patch is working.

There are other options, Dolphin, the default file manager in KDE has support for this. You could install and use Dolphin in the gnome version of Ubuntu (or use Kubuntu if you otherwise prefer KDE).

http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdebase-apps/dolphin/quick-tips.html